# Como almacenar datos importados a Python en una cache de memoria

Tags: python, cache, pandas

Trabajo con Python 3.5. y Pandas

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación la cual realiza una serie de cálculos y procesos sobre un dataframe en Pandas. Dicho dataframe lo lleno a través de un select que lanzo contra mi base de datos en SQL Server mediante la libreria pypodbc.

```
import pyodbc
import pandas.io.sql as pd

conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=GENIL\Luna;DATABASE=Central;UID=sa;PWD=1')

sql="Select IdActivo,NombreActivo,tickeractivo from Activos"
df = pd.read_sql(sql,conn)

df.head(10)
print (df)
```

Pues bien dicho select me devuelve mas de 15 millones de registros por lo que se tardan casi 10 minutos en recibirlo y almacenarlo en el dataframe de pandas para su posterior proceso.

Mi pregunta es si es posible crear y gestionar el resultado de este select en memoria caché de forma que sea mucho más rápida la carga de datos en cualquier dataframe que necesite a lo largo del proceso.

¿alguna sugerencia acerca de qué forma puedo conseguir esto?

Muchas gracias

Angel

Comment: Hola! Recuerda que estas en Stack Overflow, el cual a diferencia de sitios como Yahoo Respuestas, no es un sitio donde preguntes algo y esperes ayuda sin siquiera mostrar algo de codigo, algo de esfuerzo, para asi poder ayudarte, muestranos que has hecho, que errores tienes durante el proceso, muestranos el codigo, para asi poder ayudarte efectivamente.

Comment: No hiciste una pregunta del tema hace 2h?

Comment: Hola, la pregunta que hice hace dos horas es relativa a como calcular una media móvil sobre los datos existentes en un dataframe. Esta pregunta es referente a cómo gestionar una cache de memoria para lanzar sobre los datos almacenados en ella diferentes procesos, entre ellos por ejemplo el de mi consulta anterior. Reedito mi pregunta y pongo un ejemplo de la forma en que solicito ahora mismo los datos a SQL. Gracias

Comment: Pregunta desde la ignorancia, ¿si ya lo tienes en un `df` para qué lo quieres *cachear*?

Comment: Respuesta desde la ignorancia. Soy principiante en python. Tal y como tengo mi script cada vez que lo ejecuto me borrará mi dataframe y volverá vuelve a importarme los datos de nuevo desde SQL, verdad? Mi pregunta es cómo podria dejar un dataframe lleno con los datos de esta importación y ejecutar scripts los cuales tomaran de este dataframe "global" los datos que le hicieran falta para el proceso que ejecutara en en cada momento.

Comment: Puedes usar el modulo `pickle` que permite almacenar los datos en cache, pero solo serviría si tus datos son siempre los mismos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En resumen, lo que pides es darle *"persistencia"* al `Dataframe` para evitar releerlo de la base de datos.

**pandas** te ofrece algunas soluciones para guardar datos en local: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html

Mi recomendación es que pruebes con HDF5 ([Pytables](http://www.pytables.org/)):

```
with pd.HDFStore('store.h5') as store:
    store['df'] = df
```

Cuando necesites recuperalo:

```
with pd.HDFStore('store.h5') as store:
    df = store['df']
```

> **Nota**: asumo que la importación de pandas se realiza como `import pandas as pd` y no como `import pandas.io.sql as pd` que pone la pregunta.

Comment: Entiendo entonces que si tengo dos dataframes que almacenar en HDF5.

Comment: ...los puedes guardar ambos dataframes en el mismo fichero, cada uno con su nombre. También puedes manipularlos como tablas de modo similar a SQL usando el formato `table` para el fichero hdf5 (En la [documentación](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-hdf5) te lo explica bastante bien).

Comment: Solo un apunte, hdf5 siendo  increible para muchas cosas no es un RDMS, algunas operaciones de escritura múltiple pueden corromper el fichero. Como supongo que tus datos seguirán respaldados por la base de datos no debería ser problema pero hay que tenerlo en cuenta.